# I get jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Invalid header padding

Tags: python, flask, jwt, authorization

So I have a simple flask app.
Logging in creates a token:

```
token = jwt.encode({'user': token_data}, app.config['SECRET_KEY']).decode('utf-8')
```

The middleware looks like this:

```
def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        data = request.headers['Authorization'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        token = str.replace(str(data), 'Bearer ', '')
        if not token:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Token is missing'}), 401
        data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithms=['HS256'])['sub']
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated
```

Then I run a protected route that is `@token_required` and get the error.
`jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Invalid header padding`

Can't add another utf-8 to the middleware token, as I cant use it with `str`
What can I do?

Comment: Aren’t you missing a closing bracket on the first arg to jwt encode?

Comment: no, it was a typo, sorry, I have it in my original code.

Comment: Why is your token being decoded during creation?

Comment: Decoding with utf-8 is needed. It can be put either in the middleware or during the creation. As my token is type str in the middleware I cant decode it with utf-8

Answer (score 3):

So I removed `.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`
and also `['sub']` and it seems to work